# Can this temperature-controlled fan circuit be modified for different input voltage?

Tags: power-supply, power, pcb, components

I want to know if this same circuit can be used for 220 or 230 volt input, and if there are any components that need to be modified. C3 has 600V capacity and C1 and C2 have 250 volt.

[image: Schematic]

[Link to original circuit diagram.](http://www.circuitstoday.com/temperature-controlled-fan-regulator)

Answer (score 1):

Richman's advice is good regarding the capacitor rating. However at twice the input voltage, the caps will charge up to the trigger voltage faster. So you will need to increase - probably double - the values of C1 and C2 to maintain the same control law.

It is also unclear that the thermistors will operate correctly or even be safe at the higher voltage rating - you need to find THAT out from their datasheets.

For example, if the higher power dissipation causes increased self-heating, what will that do to the control law?

If the thermistors check out as safe at 230V, you can try the circuit, but expect some fiddling to get it working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

What are the new motor's ratings?  The new motor's voltage rating should be 220-230.  If your new motor is larger than the original motor's power / current rating, you may need to adjust the inductor/thyristor and fuse ratings.  Most likely, your motor will be the same power and so it will draw less current and so you can use the same thyristor/inductor/fuse.

Other comments regarding the cap voltage ratings and control law are good advice as well.