# Can I change the input voltage for this temperature-controlled fan circuit:?

Tags: power-supply, components, thermistor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can this temperature-controlled fan circuit be modified for different input voltage?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51972/can-this-temperature-controlled-fan-circuit-be-modified-for-different-input-volt)

[image: Temp. controlled fan]

For the above temperature-controlled fan control circuit which is originally designed for 110V supply, is it possible to operate on 220V?

Also, since the main function of slowing the fan when it's cool and speeding it up when it's hot is done by NTC, why is PTC required? Also what's the purpose of cap and inductor?

Answer (score 1):

Some of this is answered by
[Can this temperature-controlled fan circuit be modified for different input voltage?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51972/query-regarding-power-supply)

In short, even with correctly rated components for the higher voltage, (are those thermistors correctly rated?) it will probably require some adjustment to work as intended.

PTC will help to increase the sensitivity to temperature, which would otherwise be quite low.

L1 and C3 will provide some attenuation of RF noise generated by the circuit.

Comment: Random question: is Connecting NTC and PTC in that manner related to Voltage at the connecting point?? (Ref: Voltage Divider biasing of transistors)